# How can I use a sprite to specify the pushpin png I want to use in a map?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-plugins, png, sprite

After (probably) deciding on the jQuery map plugin to use (see [What jQuery map plugin allows specifying the color of the pushpins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772001/what-jquery-map-plugin-allows-specifying-the-color-of-the-pushpins)), I now need png files of colored pushpins.

I found a dandy one here: http://www.fuzzimo.com/free-vector-post-it-notes-push-pins/ :

[image]

...but it appears to be, not a collection of various png files I can use (blue.png, red.png, chartreuse.png, etc.) but one humongous .png file with an array of images. So I'm guessing this is meant to be used as a sprite. Being a sprite newby, though, I don't know how to use this image and specify the section of it that I want to use.

Specifically, the jQuery code I'll be using to set the marker's icon is like:

```
icon: '../img/apartment.png'
```

...how can I specify usage of a specific pushpin?

Comment: I've never heard of pushpin using sprite. I'm waiting for your news.

Comment: Neither have I; like I said, I'm a sprite newby; but there is such a file, like a poster of pushpins, so what use would it be otherwise?

Comment: from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons) and [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon), the google.maps.Icon definition supports sprites.

Comment: Okay, so how am I supposed to know at offset to use with the image above if, say, I want to use the bronze-colored tack fifth from the left in the second row? And do I need to do anything to make the black background transparent?

Comment: Google for "CSS sprites" See eg http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050152/why-use-a-sprite-sheet-rather-than-individual-images  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/